# dojo.byId is null in xpage js header

Tags: dojo, xpages

[dojo.byId](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/byId.html) is not working in xpage js header. Why is this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");
function test()
{

alert(dojo.byId("#{id:inputText3}").value);
}

</script>
```

I am using Xpage head tag. Also I tried this code in JS Script library and it did not work there. It worked for document.getElementById("view:_id1:_id2:inputText3").value . I want to make the code standard. main reason of adding the code in head tag is to make the function modular. Please suggest me if there is any other place I can write my code.

> Error - TypeError: dojo.byId("#{id:inputText3}") is null

Comment: Are you using `xp:headTag`? Can you please post the relevant XPage source. As you can see the ID does not end up in JS. This happens if you use Script Library.

Comment: Can you provide us with the xml from your xpage? Maybe it is because the inputText3 is not rendered/loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scriptBlock instead:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
    dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");
    function test() {
        alert(dojo.byId("#{id:inputText3}").value);
    }
    ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: dojo.byId can't work in the header since the element you are after hasn't been rendered yet. Use Per's approach or add your function call to XSP.addOnLoad(), so it executes only AFTER the page actually loaded

Comment: I am facing an error when using the dynamic field names for below formula.
for(a=2; a<8;a++)
 {
  cnt=a+1;
           inputArray[m]=eval('dojo.byId({id:inputText'+cnt+'").value') ;
  m = m+1;
 }

Comment: I think the issue is with "{". can anyone help what could be workaround. Also it worked fine for dojo.byId("#{id:inputText3}").value. So I am bit confused.